# Dynamic HREF in XSLT using attribute not working as expected

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm newer to XSLTs and I'm struggling a bit with getting this one to format correctly.  I want the output HTML to basically be rows that look like this:

```
1 : SO090040717 113657 XXX 56371444826
```

Where "SalesId" is a clickable URL that is formatted (in this example) as basically:

`<a href="dynamics://TEST?DrillDown_0?tableid=40276&field=RecId&value=5637144826&company=XXX">SO090040717</a>`

The error appears to be somewhere in the `<a></a>` text?

**Sample XML:**

```
<ELEMENT>
    <RECORD>
        <COUNTER>1</COUNTER>
        <DRILLDOWNGROUP>TEST</DRILLDOWNGROUP>
        <SalesId>SO090040717</SalesId>
        <PurchOrderFormNum>113657</PurchOrderFormNum>
        <dataAreaId>XXX</dataAreaId>
        <RecId>5637144826</RecId>
        <TableId>40276</TableId>
    </RECORD>
</ELEMENT>
```

**My, non-working, XSLT:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
<body>
<xsl:for-each select="ELEMENT">
<p>
<xsl:for-each select="RECORD">
    <p>
        <xsl:value-of select="COUNTER"/>
        <xsl:text> : </xsl:text>
        <a>
            <xsl:attribute name="href">
                <xsl:text>Dynamics://</xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="DrillDownGroup"/>
                <xsl:text>?DrillDown_0?tableid=</xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="TableId"/>
                <xsl:text>&field=RecId&value=</xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="RecId"/>
                <xsl:text>&company=</xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="DataAreaId"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:value-of select="SALESID"/>
        </a>
        <xsl:text>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="PurchOrderFormNum"/>
        <xsl:text>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="dataAreaId"/>
        <xsl:text>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="RecId"/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
    </p>
</xsl:for-each>
</p>
</xsl:for-each>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

A few things:

1. Case matters so be sure the paths in your `select` attributes are the same as the source XML.
2. `&nbsp;` The entity nbsp is not declared so use either a hex or decimal reference. You can create an entity declaration for nbsp if you want. In the example, I used the hex reference. Let me know if you want an example of the declaration for nbsp.
3. You can't use literal `&` unless you're in a CDATA section. It's easier to use `&amp;` instead. I used `&amp;` in the example. If you want to use CDATA, do something like: `<xsl:text><![CDATA[&company=]]></xsl:text>`

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <body>
                <xsl:for-each select="ELEMENT">
                    <p>
                        <xsl:for-each select="RECORD">
                            <p>
                                <xsl:value-of select="COUNTER"/>
                                <xsl:text> : </xsl:text>
                                <a>
                                    <xsl:attribute name="href">
                                        <xsl:text>dynamics://</xsl:text>
                                        <xsl:value-of select="DRILLDOWNGROUP"/>
                                        <xsl:text>?DrillDown_0?tableid=</xsl:text>
                                        <xsl:value-of select="TableId"/>
                                        <xsl:text>&amp;field=RecId&amp;value=</xsl:text>
                                        <xsl:value-of select="RecId"/>
                                        <xsl:text>&amp;company=</xsl:text>
                                        <xsl:value-of select="dataAreaId"/>
                                    </xsl:attribute>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="SalesId"/>
                                </a>
                                <xsl:text>&#xA0;&#xA0;&#xA0;</xsl:text>
                                <xsl:value-of select="PurchOrderFormNum"/>
                                <xsl:text>&#xA0;&#xA0;&#xA0;</xsl:text>
                                <xsl:value-of select="dataAreaId"/>
                                <xsl:text>&#xA0;&#xA0;&#xA0;</xsl:text>
                                <xsl:value-of select="RecId"/>
                                <br/>
                                <br/>
                            </p>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </p>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<html>
   <body>
      <p>
         <p>1 : <a href="dynamics://TEST?DrillDown_0?tableid=40276&amp;field=RecId&amp;value=5637144826&amp;company=XXX">SO090040717</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;113657&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;XXX&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;5637144826<br><br></p>
      </p>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Wonderful!  Testing this now, but an example of an entity declaration would be fantastic too!  I should have known that literal `&` would have been an issue.  The `&nbsp` seems to have worked though once I deleted out the `<a></a>` block?

Comment: Also, is there anyway to force my XSL to handle any case or just be case-insensitive?